# How to clear item not input when count frequency use Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I'm newbie. I want count frequency when I input numbers by use dictionary.
Because I use array[100]. 
Size of array: 3
Input: 1 2 3
Result:
1: 1 time
2: 1 time
3: 1 time
0: 97 times

Please help me !
[Run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzLCL.png)

Implement code:

```
 {
        Console.WriteLine("Count frequencies of array: ");

        int[] arr = new int[100];
        int n, i;

        Console.Write("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Input {0} elements in the array :\n", n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("element - {0} : ", i);
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        //Create a dictionary to store the counts.
        Dictionary<int, int> valCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (int x in arr)

        {
            if (valCount.ContainsKey(x))
                valCount[x]++;
            else
                valCount[x] = 1;
        }


        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in valCount)

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: " + "{1} times", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

        Console.Write("Press any key to close the console app...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: But what is the actual issue? What are the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using fixed size array, `foreach` loop will always iterate 100 times.

As I see in your code, you first gets input how much inputs you will accept as `n`. So you may use it to limit the count of the loop. Like:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (valCount.ContainsKey(x))
        valCount[x]++;
    else
        valCount[x] = 1;
}
```

Comment: I see. Thank you a lot !